# Elasticsearch migration from 6.8 to 7.9. [config validation of [elasticsearch].url]: definition for this key is missing

Tags: elasticsearch, migration

I have the following error during the migration of our Elasticsearch instance from version 6.8 to 7.9:

```
FATAL  Error: [config validation of [elasticsearch].url]: definition for this key is missing
```

The whole configuration is the same.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

kibana.yml should look like this

```
server.host: "0.0.0.0"

elasticsearch.url: http://127.0.0.1:9200

kibana.index: ".kibana"
```

and also you can pass as an environment variable

```
SERVER_NAME: kibana
ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://127.0.0.1:9200
```

Here's [a link](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/config/kibana.yml)
for more kibana config options.

Answer (score 0):

Enable elasticsearch.hosts in config/kibana.yml,

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200/"]
```

That should solve your problem.